# Ansible Playbook creating BitBucket Repository

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a BitBucket Repository via Ansible Playbook.
However, running the following command using RestAPI works fine:

```
curl -u user:Password \
     -d '@data.json' \
     -X POST \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     http:// https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/projects/SUN/repos
```

JSON includes the following:

```
{"name": "my-repo",
 "scmId": "git",
 "forkable": true}
```

I tried all kind of ways to convert this curl command to an ansible playbook but it`s always failing with different errors.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Create a Bitbucket Repo
      uri:
        url: https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/projects/SUN/repos
        method: POST
        user: user
        password: password
        src: data.json
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 201
        body_format: json
```

When leaving "tasks" it says playbook needs to be a list of plays.
When removing tasks it says "uri" is not valid attribute.

Can anyone advise on the structure the playbook should have in this example?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try [uri](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) module.

Comment: Yes I did. Turned out that issue was in inventory file. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

The "tasks needs to be a list" message generally means you either

- forgot a `-` (dash) before a task

  ```
  - hosts: localhost
    tasks
       name:  # no dash here.
       uri:
       # ...
  ```
- misindented something.

I Re-formatted your code. It looks OK to me, as reformatted. Double check what you have in your playbook. But you do need the `tasks:` keyword or you will get the second error message you mention for sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.At the end my code worked after I edited the Host file.Turned out that I needet to add _SSH after ansible_ssh_user=xxx and ansible_ssh_pass=xxx